# How can I get a response from an observable immediately?

Tags: angular, observable, angularfire2

I need to know if the user is signed in, but when I check, the AngularFireAuth hasn't given a response yet, and so it thinks I'm not signed in when I am.

My service:

```
loggedIn = false;

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user=>{
    this.loggedIn = true;
  });
}
```

then I have my Guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class OnlyLoggedInUsersGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private user: UserService) {}

  canActivate(){
      return this.user.loggedIn? true:false;
  }
```

When I try to open the dashboard it says I'm not logged in, because it's checking after the service is constructed, but before the observable is changing `loggedIn` to true.

Comment: by `immediately` what you mean?

Comment: this.loggedIn=true isn't happening right away, and so the guard checks before it happens, and so it's false. Then after the guard checks it turns true, but it's too late at that point

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your `UserService` you can set:

```
private loggedInSubject = new BehaviorSubject<bool>(false);
public loggedIn = this.loggedInSubject.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged();

constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth
) {
  this.afAuth.authState
      .subscribe(user=> {
          this.loggedInSubject.next(true);
      });
}
```

You can then call it like this inside of your `Guard`:

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.user.loggedIn.take(1);
}
```

Comment: `[ts]
Class 'OnlyLoggedInUsersGuard' incorrectly implements interface 'CanActivate'.
  Types of property 'canActivate' are incompatible.
    Type '() => Observable<Boolean>' is not assignable to type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => boolean | Observable<boolean> | Pr...'.
      Type 'Observable<Boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean>'.
        Type 'Observable<Boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<boolean>'.
          Property 'then' is missing in type 'Observable<Boolean>'.`

Comment: I think it wants an answer right away, I tried using a promise but got the same error.

Comment: @Jus10 I edited `canActivate` function, try to copy that one.

Comment: No errors, but still not functioning in the correct order.

Comment: @Jus10 I'm not sure how you actually even created the race condition. You should have `login` function which is called when user enters credentials, if credentials are correct, it should save it's state inside your service. If user was previously logged in, you should check it inside of your `AppModule` and set the correct value based on it inside your `UserService`. If you do so, you will avoid this race condition.

Comment: Ya, I'm re-writing everything, definitely doing this wrong. It think it's an XY problem. TY for your help!

Comment: @Jus10 No problem, glad I helped.